# Symfony 4 : Redirect to /admin when try to get /

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I try to figure out my problem which occured few hours ago. When I try to access `mywebsite.com/` symfony redirects me to `mywebsite.com/admin` which is a url that doesn't exist so it throws a 404 error.

> No route found for "GET /admin/"

I looked every where on my projet to try to understand the cause but I didn't find anything. Then a friend ask my to try his project and curiously when I tried to reach the `/` it also redirect me to `/admin` which driving me crazy.

Do you have any idea of what is happening?

Thanks,

A.

Comment: Does the request reach the server at all? Maybe it's browser's cache (that may be checked in browser's developer tools)? If not, then use xdebug to track the code which does the redirect.

Comment: Did you cleared the cache? You may have done changes that aren't taken in account yet

Comment: sounds like a server issue not an issue with symfony itself - what are you using? apache? nginx? Do you have redirects set up maybe?

Comment: Thanks for your answers! I deleted the cache and every things works fine now. Thank you very much :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments of my initial post I figur this out by cleaning the cache of Chrome.

Thanks guys

Comment: [FYI, you can have it so Chrome doesn't cache when developer tools is open.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690269/disabling-chrome-cache-for-website-development)